# Grails: disable Foreign key constraints

Tags: grails, foreign-keys, grails-orm

I am using grails 3.3.2.
Is there any way to remove the auto generated foreign key constraints?
Thanks.

I have tried:

1. grails schema-export
2. remove those lines like "alter table xxx add constraint yyy foreign key zzzz..."
3. change dbCreate: none

But it's not convenient especially when domain class changed.

Comment: Why do you need this? Can you give an example?

Comment: It's a read only application. It's not convenient while importing data.

Comment: Do you want it remove permanently or temporary?

Answer (score 0):

You have the 2 options to remove the foreign key constraints of your database.

1. Remove **static belongsTo** from your domain class which is mapping to another domain ( database table )

OR

2. You can do foreign key check off at the database level from database console  (for MySql) as follows but, be careful while doing this, this may violate your foreign key constraint rule.

   ```
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; // disable foreign key check
   SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; // enable foreign key check
   ```

Comment: You need to change database config for data source as   dbCreate   =  "update", I think you "read" now

Comment: 1. Removing static belongsTo don't remove constraints. I have just tested it.
2. I want to find a way database agnostic. Maybe some configuration of Hibernate can handle it. But I have not found it yet.

Comment: You can't do that until you change the dbCreate = "update", you can go for second option mentioned in the answer above.

Comment: I just found this: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=465, But I can't follow it since the GrailsAnnotationConfiguration does not exists in Grails 3.3.2.